# z-index overlap works in webkit, not in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have a simple Twitter Bootstrap theme that consists of:

- Column 1: empty
- Columns 2-4: Logo with `z-index` of 100
- Columns 5-12: Navbar

Below that is a carousel. In Chrome/Safari the logo properly lays on top of the carousel. In Firefox however, the carousel image is pushed all the way after column 12. Here's a [link](http://jsbin.com/vedaliro/1) to the source.

Comment: It looks like the floated elements ( .navbar.navbar-default ) within #overlap are causing .carousel-inner to shift over. I was able to add .carousel { clear: both } to escape this issue. I'll keep digging to see what's up with the pseudo classes causing the float / collapse.

Comment: Narrowed it down to #overlap flac.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. Just add the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's the `height` set on `#overlap` causing it to shift over.